# Unable to SUM Distinct Values with Group By Correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to run a query the brings the total number of sales by taxable and non taxable depending on the tax rate.

```
SELECT     '$' + CAST (SUM (CASE WHEN Taxes.SalesTax = '0.06' THEN Order_Summary.CompleteSalesTax
            WHEN Taxes.SalesTax = '0.065' THEN Order_Summary.CompleteSalesTax
            WHEN Taxes.SalesTax = '0.07' THEN Order_Summary.CompleteSalesTax 
            WHEN Taxes.SalesTax = '0.075' THEN Order_Summary.CompleteSalesTax ELSE 0.0 END) AS varchar(10))
            AS 'Non-Taxable Sales',
          '$' + CAST (SUM(CASE WHEN Taxes.SalesTax = '0.06' THEN Order_Summary.CompleteSalesNonTax
            WHEN Taxes.SalesTax = '0.065' THEN Order_Summary.CompleteSalesNonTax
            WHEN Taxes.SalesTax = '0.07' THEN Order_Summary.CompleteSalesNonTax 
            WHEN Taxes.SalesTax = '0.075' THEN Order_Summary.CompleteSalesNonTax ELSE 0.0 END) AS varchar(10))
            AS 'Taxable Sales',
           CAST (Taxes.SalesTax * 100 AS VARCHAR ) + '%' AS 'Sales Tax Rate'
FROM ((Order_Label INNER JOIN Order_Summary
     ON Order_Label.OrderID = Order_Summary.SummID) INNER JOIN Taxes
     ON Order_Lablel.ZipCodeShipped = Taxes.StateZipCode)
WHERE (((Order_Label.StateShipped)= 'FLORIDA') 
AND ((Order_Label.O_Date) Between [DATE] And [DATE]))
GROUP BY TAXES.SalesTax
HAVING COUNT (*)  = 1
```

It returns results as so:

```
        |Non-Taxable Sales|Taxable Sales|Sales Tax Rate|
        |XXXXX.XX         |XXX.XX       |X.XX%         |
        |XXXXX.XX         |XXX.XX       |X.XX%         |
        |XXXXX.XX         |XXXX.XX      |X.XX%         |
        |XXX.XX           |XX.XX        |X.XX%         |
```

What my issue is, there's a unique identifier in the Order_Label table called OrderNumber. OrderNumber has duplicate values so, those are aggregating all the duplicates so my final values are much larger than what they should be. I have a group by and I implemented a DISTINCT in my query, but it's still returning incorrect values. Is there something I can implement into my query to return the correct values and maintain the Group By I have now. It should only yield the 3 columns with 4 rows as shown.

Comment: what is `Order_Lablel`?  might help to see the entire query, or one that compiles.

Comment: Order_Label is a table all its own, the query above is the entire query and runs currently with no errors. There's a column name in Order_Label called OrderNumber. In the database, there are several occurrences of the same OrderNumber with the same values in the database, if I aggregate them, some of those values, depending on how many times OrderNumber occurs it will sum those values that many times. For Ex. OrderNumber 123 occurs, 4 times with the value $100, the query will sum that as $400 when it should be just $100

Answer (score 0):

Another way, give it a try, a little bit messy :

```
WITH CteData
AS
(
SELECT Taxes.SalesTax
, Order_Summary.CompleteSalesTax
, Order_Summary.CompleteSalesNonTax 
,Dev.StateZipCode
FROM 
(
SELECT DISTINCT OrderID,ZipCodeShipped,StateShipped,O_Date FROM Order_Label
) AS Dev
INNER JOIN Order_Summary ON Dev.OrderID = Order_Summary.SummID
INNER JOIN Taxes ON Dev.ZipCodeShipped = Taxes.StateZipCode
WHERE (((Dev.StateShipped)= 'FLORIDA') 
AND ((Dev.O_Date) Between [DATE] And [DATE]))
)

SELECT DevSalesTax.[Non-Taxable Sales],DevSalesNonTax.[Taxable Sales],DevSalesTaxRate.[Sales Tax Rate]
FROM

(SELECT [Non-Taxable Sales]  = 
            (SUM 
            (CASE WHEN Taxes.SalesTax = '0.06' THEN Order_Summary.CompleteSalesTax
            WHEN Taxes.SalesTax = '0.065' THEN Order_Summary.CompleteSalesTax
            WHEN Taxes.SalesTax = '0.07' THEN Order_Summary.CompleteSalesTax 
            WHEN Taxes.SalesTax = '0.075' THEN Order_Summary.CompleteSalesTax ELSE 0.0 END)), StateZipCode            
            FROM CteData
            GROUP BY SalesTax,StateZipCode
            HAVING COUNT (*)  = 1) AS DevSalesTax 
 INNER JOIN
(SELECT [Taxable Sales] = 
            (SUM
            (CASE WHEN Taxes.SalesTax = '0.06' THEN Order_Summary.CompleteSalesNonTax
            WHEN Taxes.SalesTax = '0.065' THEN Order_Summary.CompleteSalesNonTax
            WHEN Taxes.SalesTax = '0.07' THEN Order_Summary.CompleteSalesNonTax 
            WHEN Taxes.SalesTax = '0.075' THEN Order_Summary.CompleteSalesNonTax ELSE 0.0 END)),StateZipCode             
            FROM CteData
            GROUP BY SalesTax,StateZipCode
            HAVING COUNT (*)  = 1) AS DevSalesNonTax ON DevSalesNonTax.StateZipCode = DevSalesTax.StateZipCode
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT [Sales Tax Rate] = Taxes.SalesTax * 100,StateZipCode           
            FROM CteData
            GROUP BY SalesTax,StateZipCode
            HAVING COUNT (*)  = 1) AS DevSalesTaxRate ON DevSalesTaxRate.StateZipCode = DevSalesNonTax.StateZipCode
```

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, they are two different aggregates, I apologize, I will edit my code.

Comment: np, I saw the changes, give it a try and let me know, I made changes using a derivated tables.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it still yields the same results, it's so strange.

Answer (score 0):

If an Order can be shipped to different Zipcodes, you might be in trouble.

```
SELECT  '$' + CAST (SUM(CASE WHEN Order_Label.SalesTax = '0.06' THEN Order_Summary.CompleteSalesTax
                             WHEN Order_Label.SalesTax = '0.065' THEN Order_Summary.CompleteSalesTax
                             WHEN Order_Label.SalesTax = '0.07' THEN Order_Summary.CompleteSalesTax
                             WHEN Order_Label.SalesTax = '0.075' THEN Order_Summary.CompleteSalesTax
                             ELSE 0.0
                        END) AS VARCHAR(10)) AS 'Non-Taxable Sales',
        '$' + CAST (SUM(CASE WHEN Order_Label.SalesTax = '0.06' THEN Order_Summary.CompleteSalesNonTax
                             WHEN Order_Label.SalesTax = '0.065' THEN Order_Summary.CompleteSalesNonTax
                             WHEN Order_Label.SalesTax = '0.07' THEN Order_Summary.CompleteSalesNonTax
                             WHEN Order_Label.SalesTax = '0.075' THEN Order_Summary.CompleteSalesNonTax
                             ELSE 0.0
                        END) AS VARCHAR(10)) AS 'Taxable Sales',
        CAST (Order_Label.SalesTax * 100 AS VARCHAR) + '%' AS 'Sales Tax Rate'
FROM    Order_Summary
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT  DISTINCT
                    Order_Label.OrderID,
                    Taxes.SalesTax
            FROM    Order_Label
                    INNER JOIN Taxes ON Order_Label.ZipCodeShipped = Taxes.StateZipCode
            WHERE   Order_Label.StateShipped = 'FLORIDA'
                    AND Order_Label.O_Date BETWEEN [DATE] AND [DATE]
        ) Order_Label ON Order_Label.OrderID = Order_Summary.SummID
GROUP BY Order_Label.SalesTax
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 1
```